# Subharmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider:

> if $\log u$ and $\log v$ are both subharmonic function on an open set $U$, then $\log(u+v)$ is also subharmonic on $U$.

How can I prove this?

Comment: Are you assuming that $u,v \neq 0$ and $u,v$ twice differentiable?

Comment: yes i assume that

Answer (score 2):

If $w$ is strictly positive and $C^2$ then a direct calculation shows that $\log w$ is subharmonic if and only if $w\Delta w+|\nabla w|^2 \ge 0$.  Taking $w=u+v$ we see that $\log(u+v)$ is subharmonic if and only if
$$
(u\Delta u+|\nabla u|^2)+(v\Delta v+|\nabla v|^2) +\Delta(uv) \ge 0.
$$
If $\log u$ and $\log v$ are subharmonic then  the first two terms on the left are non-negative. And so is the third because 
$$
\Delta(uv) = uv\cdot\left[\Delta(\log u+\log v) +|\nabla(\log uv|^2\right],
$$
which is clearly non-negative.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is wrong. There should be a minus sign in your criterium ("minus the norm of the gradient"), which complicates things considerably. Additionally, the first manipulation is incorrect. This is not the way to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption about the regularity is not necessary here.

Indeed, we know that we can find a sequence of smooth functions $u_n$ and $v_n$ decreasing to $u$ and $v$ respectively and such that $\log u_n, \log v_n$ are subharmonic (just use a convolution with a radial smoothing kernel).

We may then use the argument of JohnD which guarantees that $\log(u_n+v_n)$ is subharmonic. But a limit of a decreasing sequence of subharmonic functions is still subharmonic, so that $\log(u+v)$ is subharmonic.

Moreover, a direct proof (with no assumption on regularity) may be obtained once we know some basic stuff about sh functions. Namely, $f(x,y)=\log (e^x+e^y)$ defines a a convex function, non-decreasing in each variable, therefore $f(\log u, \log v)=\log(u+v)$ is subharmonic.